# Knockout two way custom binding to split ISO datetime in date and time fields

Tags: knockout.js

I've a datetimestring as `YYYY-MM-DDT03:00` from server side, and moment.js on client.

I need to bind both the update and init phase of the bindinghandler to my observable datetime property, but cannot get it to work with form input.

This is the working idea for text elements (only update phase):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);
        var value = ko.unwrap(options.value);
        var text = moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        ko.utils.setTextContent(element, text);
    },
};
ko.bindingHandlers.time = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);
        var value = ko.unwrap(options.value);
        var text = moment(value).format('HH:mm');
        ko.utils.setTextContent(element, text);
    },
};
```

**EDIT - I try to contextualize a bit my issue.**

Actually, as a knockout and js newcomer :), I'm trying to map etherogenous Json array from server (each item can have various properties) to knockout observables thru ko.mapping. Eventually I need a ko observable array with editing/save/cancel/delete methods for each original array item.

```
function EditableCollection(payload, updateUrl) {
    /* EditableCollections = { item: actual object,
     *                         data: actual data,
     *                         edit, editing Knockout facility,
     *                       }
     */
    var collection = this;
    collection.item = ko.mapping.fromJS(payload);

    collection.editing = ko.observable(false);

    collection.edit = function() {
        if (!self.condition()) {
            // UI logic
            collection._bkp = ko.mapping.toJS(collection.item);
            collection.editing(true);
        } else {
            // UI logic
        };
    };
    collection.cancel = function() {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(collection._bkp, collection.item);
        delete(collection._bkp);
        collection.editing(false);
        // UI logic
    };
    collection.item.cancel = collection.cancel;
    collection.save = function() {
        if (updateUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: updateUrl,
            method:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data: JSON.stringify($.extend(updateData, { 'item': ko.mapping.toJS(collection.item) })), // or something
            success: function(result){
            return result;
            },
            error: function(error){
            return error;
            },
        });
        };
        // UI logic
        delete(collection._bkp);
    };
    collection.item.save = collection.save;
};
```

The original question arise because somewhen I face array with items containing ISO 8601 strings that I need to transform in two separate properties date and time.

So I cannot use computedProperties I think. As a workaround the original bindings method, I resort to manage the task in mapping `create function`, but it is very inefficient and ugly to me:

```
var scadenzeMapping = {
create: function(options) {
    var payload = options.data;
    console.log(payload);
    // ** moment.js:
    // When refactoring for TIME will matter.
    var start = moment(payload.data_start); // e.g. 05/02/2018T00:00:00
    // TODO ** Verify timezone (external) handling...
    if (payload.isAllDay) {
        payload.sdate = start.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        payload.stime = undefined;
        payload.edate = payload.sdate;
        payload.etime = undefined;
        payload.data_end = payload.data_start;
    } else {
        payload.sdate = start.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        payload.stime = start.format('HH:mm');
        var end = moment(payload.data_end);
        payload.edate = end.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        payload.etime = end.format('HH:mm');
    };
    // payload.data_start = start;
    return new EditableCollection(payload,
                                  '{{ put_event }}',
                                  );
    },
};
```

This is the out-topic context of the original question.

Comment: ...I think I'll end up keeping ISO formatted datetime and separate date and time in view model...

Comment: A couple of `computed`s would serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

First, your custom bindings dont subscribe to the changes of the passed observable. If you change

```
var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);
```

to

```
var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

your update function gets called after the passed observable has changed.

---

Second, if you try to use this binding on an input, you can't use the

```
ko.utils.setTextContent(element, text);
```

since it changes the content of the element, not the value. You need to use

```
element.value = text;
```

---

I think the best way to do this kind of thing would be without custom binding, using writeable computeds, and using the standard value binding, something like this:

```
var myObservable = ko.observable();
var myComputed = ko.computed({
    write: function(val){
        myObservable(moment(val, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'))
    },
    read: function(){
        return moment(myObservable()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
})
```

And in the html:

```
<input data-bind="value: myComputed"/>
```

Comment: Undoubtably you and Ray J are true in suggesting the use of computedProperties, but my question is actually tied to ko.mapping as I try to explain in my edit above. I think the point has to be the use of init function in ko.bindingHandlers. Thanks

Comment: @user2154587 You don't need to convert them in `ko.mapping`. You can just store the unconverted date and have two `computed`s in the viewmodel that translate it to day and time.